# Partial differential equations ( Heat equation)

Tags: partial-differential-equations, heat-equation

Please, I need help on below problem.

In this problem, D is the unit disc $x^2+y^2\le1$ and $C=\delta D$ is its boundary circle. See details in the attached image.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CQ6yS.jpg)

Comment: Did you consider their hint?

Comment: I am confused with the hint.

Comment: And where do you need help specifically?